# Altering SQL Server user defined types with default value still enforce me to pass new column

Tags: c#, sql-server

We added a new column to SQL Server user defined table with a default value.
So I am expecting the old code to work and use default value but I got an error back from ado.net

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Trying to pass a table-valued parameter with 8 column(s) where the corresponding user-defined table type requires 9 column(s).

```
_typeSqlMetaData = Create table schema - old table structure
SqlDataRecord record = new SqlDataRecord(_typeSqlMetaData);
record.SetInt16(0, someData);
record.SetGuid(1, someGuid);
record.SetDecimal(2, Amount);
.
.
.
record.SetBoolean(7, someflag);
```

Comment: The error is not about default values or not default values, it's about the number of columns in your table parameter. You'll have to amend the .NET code.

Comment: Changing .net code : that what I am trying to avoid. I need a way where I can alter user-defined-type and not have to change .net code. Like we do in storedProcedures by adding new parameter with default value.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, no. Someone else may know better though. Why is it such a big deal to change the .NET code?

Comment: We have one db server with 2 app server. During deployment only one app server goes down at a time to maintain 24/7 availability. 
when db get updated with one app server the other app server with old code will stay live for customers will crash with schema changes.

Comment: I need to maintain 2 versions then.

Comment: No one ever promises 100% uptime if they have any sense. This might be one of those occasions for a few minutes of total downtime. It should not take very long to deploy the app, I would hope?

Comment: First of all: You did not add a column to an existing table type, you created a brand new type. Second: You have to alter all SPs to be able to use the new type. Summary: This should have already given you a hint that they do not work like regular tables. Would be nice to see a workaround though.